# React Router back button issue on Home Screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to push back to login screen when user presses back button of the browser  when user in Home Screen.

This is my snippet to detect back button

```
 const handleEvent = () => {
        console.log('popstate');
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('popstate', handleEvent);
        return () => window.removeEventListener('popstate', handleEvent);
    });
```

when I click browser back arrow its invoking handleEvent function but problem is in same home component I have other history.push methods, when I click on that push method again its invoking  handleEvent function.

Can someone help me to understand how to handle forward and back arrow buttons of browsers in react js.

Comment: Why are you trying to change the default back button behavior? What do you need to know of the browser navigation buttons? They navigate forward/backward through the browser's history stack.

Comment: I need to navigate login screen when user press browser back button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `history.push` for both forward and backward buttons.

Comment: I am looking for browser button actions